# Get substring of a string in java

Tags: java, substring

I have a filepath like filepath = "Y:\abc\hello\doc.txt". I want to get substring from "\doc.txt". How can I do it using Java code.

Comment: use the split method of the String class, split on \ and keep "\" + last result.

Comment: Why do you want `\doc.txt` instead of `doc.text`?

Comment: Have a look at [`Path#getFileName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#getFileName())